# Clang 7 cannot find <filesystem> header on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, clang, c++17, ninja

I wrote `CMakeLists.txt` file like below for using C++17 `<filesystem>`. These are the part of them.

```cpp
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

...

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")

include(functions)
include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported("-Wall")
enable_cxx_compiler_flag_if_supported("-pedantic")

...

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME ON)
find_package(Boost 1.65.1 COMPONENTS filesystem regex system thread)
if(Boost_FOUND)
    add_executable(daemon 
                ...)
    target_compile_features(daemon PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
    target_include_directories(daemon PRIVATE ...)
    target_link_libraries(daemon ${Boost_LIBRARIES}) 

    # OS specific instructions.
    if(APPLE)
        find_library(CoreFoundation CoreFoundation)
        find_library(IOKit IOKit)
        target_link_libraries(daemon ${CoreFoundation} ${IOKit}) 
    elseif(WIN32)
        # Windows developer environment specific instructions.
        if(MINGW)
        elseif(MSYS)
        elseif(CYGWIN)
        endif()
    elseif(UNIX)
        // The problem is here. Why Clang cannot find <filesystem>???
        target_link_libraries(daemon c++fs dl)
    else()
    endif()
endif()
```

I've tried `target_link_libraries(daemon stdc++fs dl)` and `set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi")` but not worked.

The error codes are

```sh
cmake --build .
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/daemon.dir/src/thread/serial_manager.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/daemon.dir/src/thread/serial_manager.cpp.o 
/usr/bin/clang++   -I/home/koriel/.conan/data/boost/1.65.1/conan/stable/package/f410c60ac3ae66f96115aab74b1c5fbc1a6a4a45/include -I/home/koriel/.conan/data/bzip2/1.0.6/conan/stable/package/abc45b7dce3f5194dea2377c33229fa4f20706b4/include -I/home/koriel/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/abc45b7dce3f5194dea2377c33229fa4f20706b4/include -I../include/json -I../include/queue -I../src/base64 -I../src/message -I../src/serial -I../src/thread -Wall -pedantic   -DBOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS -std=gnu++17 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/daemon.dir/src/thread/serial_manager.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/daemon.dir/src/thread/serial_manager.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/daemon.dir/src/thread/serial_manager.cpp.o -c ../src/thread/serial_manager.cpp
../src/thread/serial_manager.cpp:43:10: fatal error: 'filesystem' file not found
#include <filesystem>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Answer (score 1):

Despite `<filesystem>` being included in the [official libc++ 7](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/release_70/include/filesystem), many distributions do not include it.

I've just had a look at Xcode 10.2 (which also ships libc++ 7) and I encountered the same story: The `filesystem` header is missing in the installation.

You can have a look at your libc++ installation, it should be somewhere in `/usr` for an Ubuntu system (If you don't know where exactly, just run `find /usr -name cstdint`, this will point you to the location). If don't find the `filesystem` header in that folder you can either use `boost::filesystem` or install clang 8 as soon as it's available.